# Find span from a table containing specific aria label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a table in html containing a specific aria label using the following line

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Help"]');
```

Now I get a table with :

```
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <div class='abc'><label><a><span class='text'>Game of thrones</span></a></label></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class='abc'><label><a><span class='text'>Harry Potter</span></a></label></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class='abc'><label><a><span class='text'>X-Men</span></a></label></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class='abc'><label><a><span class='text'>X-Men 2</span></a></label></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class='abc'><label><a><span class='text'>X-Men 3</span></a></label></div>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now i want to select all spans with span class = text but does not contain x-men 2 and x-men 3 from the table I got from list

Comment: `$(".text:not(:contains(x-men 2)),.text:not(:contains(x-men 3))",$(list))` or something like this.

Comment: `id`s should not start with a number

Comment: having `div`s inside `tr` is invalid html see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644276/differing-jquery-table-results/39644390#39644390, `$('.text:not(:contains(X-Men 2),:contains(X-Men 3))')` will get the elements you want though

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop through the collection:

```
var spans = list.getElementsByTagName("SPAN"),
    count = spans.length,
    filtered_spans = '',
    i = 0;

for(; i < count; i++) {
    if (!spans[i].innerHTML.match(/X-Men\s(2|3)/gi)) filtered_spans += spans[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add another class in the span like this :

```
<table id = 5 aria-label = "Help">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><div class='abc'><label><a><span class='text'>Game of thrones</span></a></label></div></tr>
    <tr><div class='abc'><label><a><span class='text'>Harry Potter</span></a></label></div></tr>
    <tr><div class='abc'><label><a><span class='text'>X-Men</span></a></label></div></tr>
    <tr><div class='abc'><label><a><span class='text x-men-2'>X-Men 2</span></a></label></div></tr>
    <tr><div class='abc'><label><a><span class='text x-men-3'>X-Men 3</span></a></label></div></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can do this after :

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('span.text:not(.x-men-2):not(.x-men-3)');
```

Comment: Class is same as text. You should read the question and should not just change the question