# Differing jquery table results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While attempting to get the proper jquery for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643350/find-span-from-a-table-containing-specific-aria-label) I ran into a question. Shouldn't each of these have similar outputs? The first one doesn't even output the `class` of the `div`s

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Help"]');
console.log('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&');
$('[aria-label="Help"] tr div').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
  console.log($(this).text());
});
console.log('&&THIS ONE WORKS&&&');
$('.text:not(:contains(X-Men 2),:contains(X-Men 3))').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
console.log('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&');
$('[aria-label="Help"] .text:not(:contains(X-Men 2),:contains(X-Men 3))').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
console.log('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&');
$('.text:not(:contains(X-Men 2),:contains(X-Men 3))',$(list)).each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id=5 aria-label="Help">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <div class='abc'>
        <label><a><span class='text'>Game of thrones</span></a></label>
      </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div class='abc'>
        <label><a><span class='text'>Harry Potter</span></a></label>
      </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div class='abc'>
        <label><a><span class='text'>X-Men</span></a></label>
      </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div class='abc'>
        <label><a><span class='text'>X-Men 2</span></a></label>
      </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div class='abc'>
        <label><a><span class='text'>X-Men 3</span></a></label>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a `div` inside a `tr` is invalid html, so the browser "fixes" the layout for you, breaking your selectors that rely on the expected hierarchy.

Here's what the inspector shows:

```
<div class="abc">
  <label><a><span class="text">Game of thrones</span></a></label>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <label><a><span class="text">Harry Potter</span></a></label>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <label><a><span class="text">X-Men</span></a></label>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <label><a><span class="text">X-Men 2</span></a></label>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <label><a><span class="text">X-Men 3</span></a></label>
</div>
<table id="5" aria-label="Help">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bduhtfL6/